# How to use foreach string output elsewhere c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, foreach

if I run the code (below) , I will get "b" as a result, I am wondering why my string method only returns me "b". If I print the string inside the foreach loop it will return "dcab", as soon as I try to use it elsewhere it wouldnt work and only give me the last item which is "b" . Thanks to anyone trying to help :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string value;
        public string output;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Test());
          
        }


        public string Test()
        {

            string[] letters = { "d", "c", "a", "b" };

            string blabla;

           
            foreach (string value in letters)
            {
                output = value;
            
            }

           return output;
        }
     
    }

      }
```

Comment: why should it return something else? in loop you're constantly reassigning the same variable, so at the end of it - `output` will contain last value from array

Comment: `return string.Concat(letters);`

Answer (score 1):

You're replacing the `output` string each time through the loop. It sounds like what you *actually* want is to append to it.

Try changing:

```
output = value;  // Replace
```

To:

```
output += value;  // Append
```

Comment: Thanks wors as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the variable output to the current value in the loop. Thus when exiting the loop you return the LAST value assigned to output.

You can add the value to the string by:

```
output += value;
```

or by using a string builder (better when dynamically adding to a string as strings are immutable)

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var value in letters) {
    builder.append(value);
}

return builder.ToString();
```